# Cocoa - NSDictionary objectForKey - memory management clarification

Tags: cocoa, memory-management, nsdictionary

[I have read the Cocoa memory management rules, but still want to be certain, and would like to know if this is good form.]

My class has a mutable dictionary ivar:

```
NSMutableDictionary *m_Dict;

...

m_Dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:10];
[m_Dict retain];
```

At some point I'll add a mutable array to the dictionary:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:100];
[m_Dict setObject:array forKey: @"myArray"];
```

At this point, I believe that the array object has been **retained** by the dictionary. Therefore I am **not retaining** the object prior to adding it to the dictionary. Is this correct?

Later, I will access the array, for read purposes:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [m_Dict objectForKey: @"myArray"];
```

**Q1.** What is being returned by objectForKey? Is it a pointer to the object being held in the dictionary? Or a pointer to a COPY of the object? (I am presuming simply a pointer to the existing object is being returned.)

**Q2**. What has happened here, memory management wise? I am presuming that 'array' points to an object that is **still retained** (by the owning dictionary object) and that I do not have to retain the object to work with it. Correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Q1) The same pointer to the Objective-C array that you added before is returned. No copy is made.

Q2) Correct. All items in the array are owned by the array. If something owns something else it keeps a retain count on it.

When you remove the object from the array the retain count is reduced and the object is (maybe) deallocated.